# Играть в игрушки или с игрушками?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Нужно было написать вчера такую фразу, а я внезапно задумалась: как правильно — играть в игрушки или играть с игрушками? С одной стороны, играть "во что-то" — это, скорее, речь об игре с перевоплощением, но с другой, играть с кем-то — вроде как в компании.
Как же все-таки правильно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Словарь сочетаемости дает оба варианта: например, играть с куклами и играть в куклы.

Answer (score 0):

Играть с чем-то во что-то: с куклами в дочки-матери.

Answer (score 0):

Играть в игру с игрушками.

Answer (score 0):

Игрушки обобщающее название и играть во что-то неопределённо-общее нельзя. Машинки - конкретные игрушки, можно играть в машинки и с машинками, в куклы и с куклами. Но есть и подводные камни, например, мяч. Если девочка играет с мячом, то всё понятно, а если сказать, что она играет в мяч, то не ясно ничего, поскольку игр с мячом много, но нет ни одной игры, которая называлась бы просто "мяч".

Comment: Не ясно, в чем отличие мяча от машинки в этом контексте. Почему играть в машинки можно, а в мяч нельзя?

Comment: Мы в детстве играли в мяч.